# Transaction inside transaction causes garbage collection . Any Alternate ways?

Tags: jquery, sql, cordova, transactions

I am developing an phonegap/cordova application , on which i will be using multiple transactions.

I have to list all my serialno which is stored in  the db as an list . If there is duplication of serial numbers within the table then i have to append it with type coloumn on the table .

For Eg :

If not Duplicate :  Do nothing

If Duplicate : serialno + '_' + type .

My Current Code :

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {

    tx.executeSql("select * from item", [], function(tx, res) {

        if (res != null && res.rows != null && res.rows.length > 0) {

            function iteration(i, qres) {

                var row = qres.rows.item(i);
                var serial = row.serialno;
                var itm_type = row.itemtype;

                tx.executeSql("select * from item where serialno='" + serial + "';", [], function(tx, res) {

                    if (res.rows.length > 1) {

                        serial = serial + '_' + itm_type;

                    }

                    list = list + '<li>' + serial + '</a></li>';

                    i += 1;

                    if (i < qres.rows.length)
                        iteration(i, qres);
                    else
                        theEnd();

                });



            }

            function theEnd() {

            }

            iteration(i, res);
        }

    });
}, function(e) {


}, function() {

});
```

The above code works fine . But it takes too much time to complete as count(*) item will be around 5000;
Is there any alternate ways to acheive this ??

Comment: do yourself a favor: don't nest transactions.

Comment: Yes i know thats an bad idea . But how can i acheive this one ?

Comment: wait, you know it's bad idea but you are going to do it anyway? I'm sorry that makes no sense.

Comment: But i have no other way !! For that only am posting an question here to find alternate ways to acheive my need .

Comment: you haven't stated what the 'actual' problem is; only the problem with your perceived solution.